# Updating rows using select multiple tables postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables and values:

```
Table1                 Table2                
------------------     --------              
ID | CREATED_BY        ID | NAME                   
------------------     --------              
1 |                    1  | aaa                  
2 |                    2  | bbb                   
3 |                    3  | ccc
4 |                    4  | ddd                    


Table1_2_link                                       
--------------------------                     
ID | TABLE1_ID | TABLE2_ID                                   
--------------------------                     
1 |  1         |   1                                
2 |  2         |   2                                  
3 |  3         |   3                        
4 |  3         |   4
```

I want to update the created_by column in Table1 with names values in Table2 where Table1_2_link has only one couple (TABLE1_ID, TABLE2_ID).

The result after update must be :

```
Table1             
------------------ 
ID | CREATED_BY    
------------------ 
1 |  aaa           
2 |  bbb           
3 |                
4 |
```

Is there a way to do that with a simple SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `join` with the `update`:

```
update table1 t1
    set created_by = t2.name
    from (select t12.TABLE1_ID, max(t12.TABLE2_ID) as TABLE2_ID
          from Table1_2_link t12
          group by t12.TABLE1_ID
          having count(*) = 1
         ) t12 join
         table2 t2
         on t12.TABLE2_ID = t2.id
    where t12.TABLE1_ID = t1.id;
```

The subquery on `Table1_2_link` finds the ids that have only one row.  When there is only one row, `MAX()` returns the value of the `TABLE2_ID` in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below Query:

```
update Table1 as tt1
SET CREATED_BY = tt1.NAME
FROM(
SELECT t1.ID, t3.NAME
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1_2_link t2 ON t1.id = t2.TABLE1_ID
INNER JOIN Table2 t3 ON t2.TABLE2_ID = t3.ID)
T
where T.ID = tt1.ID
```

Comment: The query update also rows with multiple couples (TABLE1_ID, TABLE2_ID). In my example ID 3 of TABLE1 is attached to IDs : 3 and 4 in Table2. This row should not be updated.